# No activity to handle ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am developing an application that needs the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission. On Android 6.0+, I create an intent with `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` to ask the user to grant the application the permission.

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION), when I call `startActivityForResult` with this intent, it is possible that I won't find an `Activity` to handle the intent.

> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you
>   safeguard against this.

What are the cases in which there might not be a matching `Activity`? And what should I do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the cases in which there might not be a matching Activity?

The manufacturer could have removed the associated `<intent-filter>` from the Settings app or otherwise reorganized that app such that there is no direct `Intent` to get to that screen.

> And what should I do in that case?

Explain to the user that you cannot take them to that screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is, I am developing a special application to be used on specific devices, not for the public, and I need to check if the user is interacting with the device to delay launching my activity until the user stops using the device, so I overlay the screen and record the time of the last touch. In the off-case that I can't overlay, then the user will be interrupted constantly with my activity, which is unacceptable of course. Do you have any suggestions in that case? Any workarounds?

Comment: @MohanadMohie: Flip the settings manually before handing the hardware over to the user. If they manually go in and mess with this setting, that's their own fault. Or, install your own custom ROM on this device, where you have locked this setting into your desired state.

Comment: The custom ROM idea is actually a good one, it was put forward by a colleague of mine but I am not sure it can be implemented in our case. Thanks again for your answer and follow-up, and I apologize for the delay in replying.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below code to take user to permission screen, and let them manually give the permission. Further by using reflection, we can try out.

```
public boolean canDrawOverlayViews () {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return true;
    }
    try {
        return Settings.canDrawOverlays (this);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
        return canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection (this);
    }

}

public boolean canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection (Context context) {

    try {
        AppOpsManager manager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService (Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        Class clazz = AppOpsManager.class;
        Method dispatchMethod = clazz.getMethod ("checkOp",
                new Class[]{int.class, int.class, String.class});
        //AppOpsManager.OP_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW = 24
        int mode = (Integer) dispatchMethod.invoke (manager,
                new Object[]{24, Binder.getCallingUid (),
                        context.getApplicationContext ().getPackageName ()});
      /* int modee = manager.checkOp(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
                Binder.getCallingUid(), context.getPackageName());

      */
        //Log.e ("mode", mode + "");

        return AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED == mode;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't used reflection before. From what I understand, and please correct me if I'm wrong, `canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection ` is a replacement for `canDrawOverlays`, which I shouldn't have any problems with even if the permission Activity doesn't exist. My problem is when I invoke `startActivityForResult ` and there is no Activity to handle this action.